# Searching for Eisenhower's (?) principle for evaluating legislation

Tags: united-states, reference-request

A few months ago, I came across a principle for evaluating legislation, and I vaguely recall it having been attributed to U.S. President Eisenhower. I did not write down the reference and I have been unable to find the quote again. Does anybody recognize it, and if so, could you please give me a reference for it? It roughly stated:

> Do not judge a law by its intended purpose, but by the ways in which it could be abused.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you're possibly remembering a quote from the Nobel Memorial Prize-winning economist Milton Friedman. In a [1975 interview](https://www.thirteen.org/openmind-archive/public-affairs/living-within-our-means/) on the Open Mind show with Richard Heffner, Friedman gave the following response when asked whether it was fair to characterize him as a conservative economist.

> **HEFFNER:** Professor Friedman, I wonder if I might begin the program by
> saying that you’re a kind gentleman, yet you’re identified by many
> with those who seem — to those who make that identification to want us
> not to do kind and gentle things — perhaps not provide for the poor,
> perhaps not provide for the aged — and I wonder how you’d reconcile
> these phenomena and whether you feel it’s fair to characterize you as
> a conservative economist.
>
> **FRIEDMAN:** Well, let me start at the end of
> that first. I never characterize myself as a conservative economist.
> As I understand the English language, conservative means conserving,
> keeping things as they are. I don’t want to keep things as they are.
> The true conservatives today are the people who are in favor of ever
> bigger government. The people who call themselves liberals today — the
> New Dealers — they are the true conservatives, because they want to
> keep going on the same path we’re going on. I would like to dismantle
> that. I call myself a liberal in the true sense of liberal, in the
> sense in which it means of and pertaining to freedom. Now,
> that brings me to your second point. **One of the great mistakes is to
> judge policies and programs by their intentions rather than their
> results.** We all know a famous road that is paved with good intentions.
> The people who go around talking about their soft heart — I share
> their — I admire them for the softness of their heart, but
> unfortunately, it very often extends to their head as well, because
> the fact is that the programs that are labeled as being for the poor,
> for the needy, almost always have effects exactly the opposite of
> those which their well-intentioned sponsors intend them to have.